# Second monitor not detected but only mirrors screen

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, radeon

I recently installed Ubuntu (Version 22.04).

At first both monitors functioned as a extended display, but they always **blacked out** shortly after the boot.

I added `nomodeset` to grub to stop the displays to black out. In this configuration the display stayed on but they displayed the same image (**mirror**).

After updating my graphic drivers (AMD Radeon R9 390) i got rid of the blackscreen (even without `nomodeset` in the grub file) but the screens are still mirroring.

This is the information about my graphics card:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 80
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:dfe00000-dfe3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1920,1080

$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390] (rev 80)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290/390]
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii HDMI Audio [Radeon R9 290/290X / 390/390X]
```

This is my `xrandr` output:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

[screenshot of "Displays" in settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpjEI.png)